# how to access this array on a servlet?

Tags: javascript, arrays, servlets, request

```
function getboxvalues(){
var array = [];
$("input:checkbox[name=delbox]:checked").each(function() {
                array.push($(this).val());
            });
            
JSON.stringify(array);
console.log(array);

   $.ajax({
    url: 'Deletestudent',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        object: {"delbox":array}
    },
    type: 'GET'
    });
}
```

Edit :
this is the servlet Code
i might have to parse the object im getting but as i was trying to get it to work , most people were just suggesting accessing it through the ususal way .

```
public class Deletestudent extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Deletestudent() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String[] idlistString = request.getParameterValues("delbox");
        
        
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("delbox"));
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

i tried accessing it through request.getparameter , but it returns as null eventho i tried logging it in the JS file and it comes out as a normal array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You have forgotten about `object` entirely even though you explicitly put it in your data
2. jQuery follows the PHP-ism of renaming parameters with array values so they have `[]` appended to them and you didn't account for that.

Your URL is going to look something like:

```
/Deletestudent?object%5Bdelbox%5D%5B%5D=foo&object%5Bdelbox%5D%5B%5D=bar
```

So you need to ask something with the right name.

```
request.getParameter("object[delbox][]"));
```

Comment: this worked pretty well for me , thanks alot .

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `POST` method as you are trying to send a JSON data.
Then you will get as request.getparameter as String, but again you may need to make that to JSON to use it easily.

Comment: even if i change it to a post request , it still returns null on the server side .

Comment: Can you please update the question with the Servlet code as well?

Comment: They aren't trying to send JSON data and there is no need to use POST for the data they are sending.